# Копирование картинки из тега img

Tags: c#, winforms, вконтакте

есть [капча](https://vk.com/captcha.php?sid=1) при обновлении страницы появляеться новая.

тоесть вариант с получением ссылки на картинку не подоедет (src).

Как скопировать данную картинку в Bitmap программным методом?

Comment: Бред, для этого используется генератор изображений.

Comment: А у вас впф или винфорс?