# Скриншот формы c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать скриншот части формы? Например координаты и ширина и высота

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Метод скриншотит любой отдельный контрол или форму(она тоже является контролом).

Даже если часть контрола скрыта.

```
    public Bitmap GetControlScreenshot(Control control)
    {
        // запоминаем размеры контрола
        Size szCurrent = control.Size;
        //ресайзим контрол до возможного максимума перед скриншотом
        control.AutoSize = true;
       
        //создаем картинку нужных размеров
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height);

        //копируем изображение нужного контрола в bmp
        control.DrawToBitmap(bmp, control.ClientRectangle);
        
        //возвращаем изначальные настройки контрола
        control.AutoSize = false;
        control.Size = szCurrent;

        return bmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Пример:

```
        Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);
        printscreen.Save(@"C:\printscreen.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

В параметры CopyFromScreen вы можете подставить свои координаты.